# Does mono on Linux require X?

Tags: mono

With C#, you can create console apps. Well, do they run in Mono without X?

I know, this might be a dumb "Dude, just try it"-question, but the point is that I can't. I don't have any Linux installation right now, I'm going to use Mono to make a Raspberry Pi I'll order of use. Since the Pi's not here yet, I can't really try by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely run console apps on Mono on the Raspberry Pi. That's what I use mine for, mostly :)

As an aside, I'd suggest installing the Arch distribution; at least when I installed mine, it had the most stable build of Mono under that environment. See [my Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/u/0/109123888989768381249/posts/hUhuf4zcDLj) for a few more details and some other handy tips from folks.